# How do I start my Spring container once for multiple selenium tests

Tags: selenium, spring-boot, junit

I followed tutorial [JSF - Primefaces Automated Unit Testing using Selenium](https://www.codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-automated-unit-testing-selenium.html) without issues (it continues from [JSF - PrimeFaces Example using Spring Boot and Maven](https://www.codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-example-spring-boot-maven.html)).

My question is, how to have multiple such tests?

The reason for asking is, when I created additional such test, my Spring Boot PF application is starting before second test, but fails on "port already in use" error.

Preferably I want my Spring Boot appplication to start once and not restart in between tests as it starts in 30 seconds with is too long for a developer to do modify-test round...

Comment: So effectively your question is: _'How do I start my Spring container once for multiple selenium tests'_ and not PrimeFaces related right?

Comment: Very likely you are correct and it is not PF related.

Comment: Then 'improve' your title since it might 'scare off' spring/selenium users not using PrimeFaces (no idea why, since everybody should use PrimeFaces

Comment: Ok, I changed it and I removed PF tag as it might not be related to the issue...